# Can i know where from i run service's method, from controller or from command?

Tags: symfony

Can i do this? I just don't want pass extra parameters for this. I want have little different behavior for command (do some echo and write in db) and for controller (only write to db).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i can inject in my service RequestStack instance:

```
active_mq:
        class: Foo\BarBundle\DependencyInjection\ActiveMQ
        arguments:
            - "@service_container"
            - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
            - "@request_stack"
```

And than:

```
$currentRequest = $this->request->getCurrentRequest();
```

If $currentRequest is null it is command, else it is controller.